# Mixing C++ and Objective-C (Suspected Automake problem)

Tags: c++, objective-c, gcc, automake

So, I've been working for some time on connecting hashing out a trivial application, comprising C++ and Objective-C, to prove some concepts and try and learn something.

Here's where I'm at now, my command (being run, and re-run on changes) is

```
$ autoreconf -vis && make clean && ./configure && make && ./src/greetings
```

Note, that I'm hoping that it'll run when I'm done, here's a brief file list:

```
$ find . | ack '\.(?:cpp|mm|h)$'
./src/darwin/greet.cpp
./src/darwin/greeting.h
./src/darwin/greeting.mm
./src/greet.h
./src/main.cpp
./src/mingw32/greet.cpp
./src/mingw32/greet.h
```

The files in full, can all be found in this [Gist at Github](https://gist.github.com/719ed9df25b1361cd89d).

Rather than being a problem specifically with mixing the languages ( I don't even make it that far) - I appear to stumble at the compiler not recognising that this is `Objective-C` (or `ObjecC++`) - for that reason, my autoconf files are in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/2cebdd69290725dad50b).

With the complete error output [here, also in a Gist](https://gist.github.com/cac6d998a3efffaffacd).

Here's a sample:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ios:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:45,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iostream:45,
                 from darwin/greet.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stringfwd.h:48: error: template with C linkage
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stringfwd.h:51: error: template with C linkage
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stringfwd.h:54: error: template with C linkage
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stringfwd.h:58: error: template specialization with C linkage
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stringfwd.h:63: error: template specialization with C linkage
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd:49,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ios:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:45,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iostream:45,
                 from darwin/greet.cpp:10:
```

Comment: Have you tried renaming `.cpp` files with the `.mm` extension?

Comment: Yes, if I do that then the automake finds no input files, however when I comment out the line `greetings_CFLAGS = -framework -Xlinker Foundation` in `./src/Makefile.am` then the errors all change to something like `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/istream.tcc:406: error: template with C linkage`

Comment: Can you add `Makefile` or `Makefile.in` to your gist? I'm wondering if perhaps a suffix rule for `.mm -> $(OBJEXT)` is missing and that's why there's no input file stuff.

Comment: Jack [`makefile`](http://gist.github.com/591261) and [`./src/Makefile.in`](http://gist.github.com/591262)

Comment: Can you upload a `make dist` somewhere for me to tinker with?

Comment: @Jack, here's the file [`autotools.zip`](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?iycpnexl543qc16) hosted at some junk 3rd party hoster :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From playing around with the zip file, here is what I recommend:

Use a C-only interface on the language boundary. This will avoid automake's non-existent Objective-C++ support. Use the

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
```

trick on your headers to ensure that the C++ compiler is going to generate C functions and the Objective-C compiler can handle the headers. This will make it possible for the Objective-C code to call your interface.

Set up your source tree as you have before: common code in `src/`, OS-specific code in `src/darwin`, `src/msdos` (:P), `src/win32` and so on. List all sources in `EXTRA_foo_SOURCES` in `Makefile.am`.

In `configure.ac`, test which platform you are compiling for and use `AM_CONDITIONAL` to set flags that `Makefile.am` can read (you've done this correctly already).

In `Makefile.am`, use the conditionals to include the correct additional sources:

```
if OS_DARWIN
  foo_SOURCES += darwin/foo.m darwin/bar.h darwin/baz.m
  foo_LDFLAGS = -Wl,-framework,Foundation
endif
```

Note that because of [how the linker is chosen](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/automake/How-the-Linker-is-Chosen.html), a C++ link will be attempted. Additional linker flags to make the Objective-C code link will need to be in `foo_LDFLAGS`.

What had happened in your case was the following: In `greet.h`, you did not declare `void greet();` as `extern "C"`. This meant that when `main.cpp` was compiled, it expected a `void greet()` that had C++ linkage (in my case, the symbol was `greet`). `darwin/greet.cpp` was compiled and had `void greet()` declared as `extern "C"`, so it produced a C version (with the symbol `_greet`). Linking then failed because the linker expected a `greet` symbol but nothing provided that.

Answer (score 0):

Your "template with C linkage" problem is due to the `#include <iostream>` inside the `extern "C"` block. Try something like this:

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <iostream>

/* In a #ifdef __cplusplus block, if you want. */
extern "C"
void greet() {
  /* ... */
}
```

This will make `greet()` have C linkage, without the headers getting misinterpreted.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense, when I do that though - the problem is that it goes back to not finding the greet() symbol?